# How to remove document in two different collection using same id at same time in mongodb on feathers application

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, feathersjs

I'm trying to remove document in two different collection using same id at same time. Is there any possibilities?

**user collection:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a310315f685dd5038fecaaa"),
    "userId" : 3,
    "accountId" : 1,
    "userType" : "DRIVER",
    "firstName" : "Karthi",
    "lastName" : "keyan",
    "email" : "karthikeyan.a1@gmail.com",
    "password" : "$2a$12$KFYc6riMnqTuzXhR0ssKZQmejAU4RF8FthAIQD4sgOUcALesp7DaJxK",
    "phone" : "xyz",
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2017-12-13T10:38:13.492Z"),
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-12-13T10:38:13.492Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

**worker collection:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a310315f685dd5038fecaab"),
    "workerId" : 1,
    "accountId" : 1,
    "name" : "Karthikeyan",
    "email" : "karthikeyan.a1@gmail.com",
    "mobile" : "xyz",
    "type" : "DRIVER",
    "joinDate" : ISODate("2017-12-13T10:38:13.070Z"),
    "assignedVehicleId" : "23423231",
    "licenseNumber" : "TN2506",
    "createdBy" : "1",
    "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-12-13T10:38:13.070Z"),
    "updatedBy" : "1",
    "updatedDate" : ISODate("2017-12-13T10:38:13.070Z"),
    "regularHours" : 3600,
    "regularRates" : 1500,
    "overtimeRates" : 400,
    "distanceRate" : 1000,
    "stopRate" : 50,
    "workerStatus" : "AVAILABLE",
    "userId" : 3,
    "__v" : 0
}
```

now i want to remove these two document at same time using userId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database adapters allow to call `remove` with `null` and a query that will remove all entries matching that query (see [the documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/databases/common.html#adapterremoveid-params---promise)). In your case:

```
app.service('users').remove(null, { query: { userId: 3 } });
app.service('workers').remove(null, { query: { userId: 3 } });
```

Removing related entries (e.g. remove all workers for that user once the user has been removed) can be done in an `after` [hook](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/hooks.html):

```
app.service('users').hooks({
  after: {
    async remove(context) {
      const user = context.result;

      await context.app.service('workers').remove(null, {
        query: { userId: user.userId }
      });
    }
  }
});
```